# Decode fixed string from integers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, integer

I am presented with two 32-bit integers which have a fixed length eight character ASCII string encoded in them.

For example, the string "HEYTHERE" is split into "HEYT" and "HERE" and each is split into four bytes to give 0x48455954 and 0x48455245 or 1212504404 and 1212502597 respectively.

What's the most efficient way of converting these two numbers back into a string in Javascript?

So far I have the following but I'm wondering if there is faster / less clumsy way:

```
let xx1 = [ 1212504404, 1212502597 ];
let xx1str = String.fromCharCode((xx1[0] >> 24) & 255) +
    String.fromCharCode((xx1[0] >> 16) & 255) +
    String.fromCharCode((xx1[0] >> 8)  & 255) +
    String.fromCharCode( xx1[0]        & 255) +
    String.fromCharCode((xx1[1] >> 24) & 255) +
    String.fromCharCode((xx1[1] >> 32) & 255) +
    String.fromCharCode((xx1[1] >> 8)  & 255) +
    String.fromCharCode( xx1[1]        & 255);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have a hash table of two characters or four characters.

```js
hash2 = { '4040': 'AA', '4041': 'AB',
         '4845':'HE',
         '5954':'YT',
         '4845':'HE',
         '5245':'RE'
        }
function madDecode(num) {
  return hash2[num.toString(16).substr(0, 4)] 
  + hash2[num.toString(16).substr(4, 4)]

}
out.innerHTML = madDecode(0x40404041) +', '
  + madDecode(1212504404) + madDecode(1212502597)
```

```html
<span id=out></span>
```

You can improve further by using 4 character hash. And even further to use array instead of object.

```js
hash2 = []

function chCode(x) {
  x = x.toString(16)
  while (x.length < 2) x = '0' + x
  return x
}

function makeHash() {
  for (var i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
    for (var j = 32; j < 128; j++) {
      hash2[parseInt(chCode(i) + chCode(j), 16)] = String.fromCharCode(i, j)
    }
  }
}

function arrDecode(num) {
  var na = (num & 0xffff0000) >> 16,
    nb = num & 0xffff
  return hash2[na] + hash2[nb]
}

makeHash()
document.write(arrDecode(1212504404) + arrDecode(1212502597))
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the look up approach although as my case has to be for any generic string encoded in this way, the cached look up would probably have to be unreasonable large. To be honest I was rather hoping that someone would show me a neat facility built into the language which would allow me to do this in less code and preferably without all the shifts and 'and's that my effort uses.

Comment: why would you need this anyway?

Comment: To present data, provided by a system in the form of two 32-bit integers, to an interface which takes an eight character string as input. It is not possible to change either the output of the first system or the input to the second, so conversion is necessary.